# Nginx can't connect to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, puma

i found myself following this tutorial "How To Deploy a Rails App with Puma and Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04" (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) in order to use ngnix as load balancer.
i followed all the steps and works fine, i suppose, but at the end, when i configured the nginx config file, i can't access into the localhost (0.0.0.0:3000) it shows "Unable to connect". i checked if the process is running and yes...

Here i let some files

/etc/nginx/sites-available/iaw2015.conf

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:///var/www/iaw2015/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/iaw2015/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

i ran this command `sudo ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/iaw2015.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/iaw2015.conf` to create the link.

config/puma.rb (in my project)

```
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 2

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `0.0.0.0:3000` being localhost. `127.0.0.1:3000` would be a port on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted, nothing is running on port 3000 that you are trying to connect to. Instead, an app server is running on a socket located at:

```
/var/www/iaw2015/shared/sockets/puma.sock
```

First, check that the app is running that you can [communicate with it through the socket](https://gist.github.com/nuxlli/7553996).

Next, try connecting to http://127.0.0.1/  This will connect to port 80, where Nginx is running. It should hopefully proxy to your app and return a result.

Comment: i'm using a virtualbox with ubuntu, maybe it has something to do with it because in my Mac i exec the same commands and it works.